# android paint using bitmaps as a paint object

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am building a drawing app and would like to create custom brushes.  I assumed there was a way to set your `android.graphics.Paint` object to use a bitmap along the path instead of a color, but this doesn't seem to be the case..  I suppose i could just save the path and draw bitmaps to it, but that seems excessive..  before i start trying to come up with a custom solution i was wondering if anyone has already tackled this.  The idea is lets say i had a 'star' icon, id like to be able to draw a line of stars based on stroke width to the path the user has drawn..

Psuedo code:

```
drawPath = new Path();
drawPaint = new Paint();
//drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
drawPaint.setBitmap(bitmap); /// <-- wouldn't that be sweet
```

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind.. i found it.. i knew i could do this..

```
drawPaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(bm, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
```