# first path isn't painted

Tags: java, android, image, draw, custom-view

I have made a custom view to paint over a bitmap. The problem is when try to paint the first touch don't show any thing and the color also changed in the next time , the second problem is that the when i save the image no thing is showed from the painted colores

Here is my code:

```
public class DrawView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    private ArrayList<ColouredPoint> paths ;
    private ColouredPoint mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    boolean erase;
    // Current used colour
    private int mCurrColour;
    public void setErase(boolean era){
        erase=era;
    }
    public void setColor(int colour) {
        mCurrColour = colour;
    }

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    // XML constructor
    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paths = new ArrayList<>();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPath = new ColouredPoint(mCurrColour);
        mPaint.setColor(mCurrColour);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }
    private float mX, mY;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Capture a reference to each touch for drawing
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mPath.reset();
                mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
                float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
                if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                    mX = x;
                    mY = y;}
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
                mPath = new ColouredPoint(mCurrColour);
                paths.add(mPath);
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        // Let the image be drawn first
        super.onDraw(c);
        // Draw your custom points here
        if(!erase){
            for (ColouredPoint i:paths) {
                mPaint.setColor(i.colour);
                c.drawPath(i, mPaint);}}
        else if (paths.size()>0){
            paths.remove(paths.size()-1);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Undo unknown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();}}
    /**
     * Class to store the coordinate and the colour of the point.
     */
    private class ColouredPoint extends Path{
        int colour;

        public ColouredPoint(int colour) {

            this.colour = colour;
        }
    }
}
```

how to fix this ?

Comment: make `mPath = new ColouredPoint(mCurrColour);` as the last line in the `init()`

Comment: thanks can you tell how to save the paint with the bitmap , it was working before but i don't know why it stopped saving the paint with the image ? @jafarbtech

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24081982/6082645) link to paint in a bitmap

Comment: no this is not my question , the question is after painting above an existing bitmap i want to save the image with the paint over it , but i can't do that and i don't know why ? @jafarbtech

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117398/why-the-paint-is-not-saved-with-the-bitmap @jafarbtech